# Python3 different results with LargeNumber ** 1 and 1.0

Tags: python-3.x, pow, largenumber

```
largenumber = 821424692950225218
largenumber ** 1 = 821424692950225218
largenumber ** 1.0 = 8.214246929502253e+17
int(largenumber**1.0) = 821424692950225280
```

Why the result is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presence of a floating point number forces the operation to be performed in a floating point context, which has [limited precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). On the other hand, where all the arguments are integral, Python lets `**` remain in the integer domain, precision of which is only limited by available memory. Once the result is a float, casting to `int` cannot recover the discarded information.

tl;dr: `largenumber ** 1.0` is equivalent to `float(largenumber)`.